# How can I start playing bagpipe?

Tags: technique, bagpipes

I am going to start bagpipe (either Galician, Scotish or Ireland one), but I have not clue what is the best beginning to play it.

Any tips for this instrument, in terms of music technique, please?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert. I am open to correction.

Irish pipes are called  uilleann pipes. They are much quieter than Scottish bagpipes. They also impose much less strain on the player because they are inflated only by the elbow rather than by blowing. Galician pipes are similar to the Scottish ones - but they have the harshest sound of all.

If you want to annoy the neighbours, choose Scottish or Galician. These are most suited to playing out of doors and can be heard the other side of town.

Bagpipes often play together in a marching band and they may be combined with a brass band.

If you prefer to retain your hearing into old age and stay friends with your neighbours, uilleann pipes are your best bet. They are played in a sitting position and are often used indoors.

If you wish to play with other people who have different instruments then again choose uilleann pipes - they are still loud but not deafening at close quarters. You can learn traditional Irish music and play along with fiddle (violin), guitars, flutes and whistles, bodhran (hand drum) and other instruments.

As for learning, I suggest you search online for instructional videos. I searched for uilleann Pipes and found this video immediately.

> Uilleann Pipes Lesson 1 [The Basics] Get Started

---

Finally (you may have detected some bias on my part!) uilleann pipes are *much* more expressive than the others. They can play vibrato and 'bend' notes.

---

> Irish traditional music : "The Chieftains" play " O'Sullivan's March"

> Galician Bagpipes in Santiago de Compostela Spain

> Band of HM Royal Marines, Scotland and Scots Guards Pipes Drums

Answer (score 3):

You can start out with a practice chanter, which is just the melodic part of the pipes, to begin working on your notes and technique, and is much less expensive than a full set of pipes. Some people start off with the Penny whistle to get started on basic finger technique.

There is a type of bagpipe called the "Parlor Pipes" or "smallpipes" that is a smaller and quieter version that is often used for indoor playing and practicing.

Choosing what type to play after that, either Highland, Galician, Uilleann, Gaida or one of the other types will be influenced by what style of music you want to play, as each has its own distinct sound, and different methods/techniques of playing.

Answer (score 2):

A friend who plays one told me that you start with the *chanter*, which is the part you play the melody on and can be played independently of the drones and the bag, making it quieter and easier to handle.